# IntelliJ Idea when testing multiple modules at once only artifacts from one module are included

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a project which uses Maven with 3 modules: a parent one, core, and addon. Core has the same artifacts as parent, but addon has an additional one. When I run tests for addon only everything works okay. The problem occurs when I test both modules at once. The tests act as if the addon module didn't have that additional artifact which, causes tests fails. Again, this only occurs when I test both modules at once. Below you can find my configuration.

[image: config]

Parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.mibac138.argparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>Binder</module>
        <module>Core</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.source>1.6</java.source>
        <java.target>1.6</java.target>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.2</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>JCenter</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testifyproject.mock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nhaarman</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.dokka</groupId>
            <artifactId>dokka-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-kotlindocs</id>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source}</source>
                    <target>${java.source}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Core pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.github.mibac138.argparser</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>argparser-core</artifactId>

</project>
```

Addon pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.github.mibac138.argparser</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>argparser-binder</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.mibac138.argparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>argparser-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Specifically, the `kotlin-reflect` acts is it wasn't there when running test across whole project.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting (because the poms are fine)?

Comment: @EngineerDollery the tests fail when I run all of them (across the whole project). It seems like the `kotlin-reflect` is missing in the addon module like if it wasn't there. However when I run tests only in the addon module they are working perfectly fine

Comment: Surely if it were missing you'd get a NoClassDefFoundError and a stack-trace due to the library being missing from the runtime classpath? Can you try it from the shell using maven? Maybe it's an intellij thing. A simple `mvn clean install` at the root should run all your tests. If that works, see if the same thing works in idea (highlight clean and install in the maven window and then run them from the context menu).

Comment: Tested it and this problem didn't occur. It only occurs when I run the tests using configuration in the question. The actual error is: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeImpl.getClassifier()Lkotlin‌​/reflect/KClassifier‌​;` which from my interpretation occurs because only `kotlin-reflect` implements given type and intellij doesn't include it while addon runs (seems like intellij includes only the artifacts for parent module). Is this a IDE bug?